# If Britain Had Ice From a Different Direction

Tags: geography, ice

At the height of the last ice age, glaciers as thick as one mile reached as far down south in Europe as London.  This is the reason why England and Wales have very little mountains, and why the terrain of their northern neighbor, Scotland, is so rugged.

But let's say, in this alternate last ice age, that the European ice reached not as far **south** as London, but as far **west** as London.  What kinds of differences should I expect to see in the terrain and topography of the British Isles?

Comment: I though mountains and landscapes was more the fact of tectonics than climate. I may be wrong but I can't see where the link is. Besides from corrosion.

Comment: Where is the ice coming from? The reason it "reached as far down south" was because the ice caps are in the north, and it was larger so it covered more to the south. Why did you ask about the west? What do you mean when you ask about what I'd it reaches "as far **west** as London"?

Comment: @Kii: Think of glacial landscaping as loosely like sanding wood- the sandpaper (ice) rubs one direction across the wood (land), then back again, smoothing away rough areas in process.

Comment: @Kii you are missing it. For example, see the Himalayas, they have ice so there are no mountains (or is it the other way around?)

Comment: It has more to do with the shape and roughness than size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a map of the last ice-age in Britain [image]

I am assuming your idea is that the ice sheet covered Sussex, Essex, Kent, Surrey, Cambridge, Norfolk and Suffolk (did I miss anyone?) and left the rest of Britan ice-free.

Glaciers have the habit of changing V-shaped valleys into U-shaped one leaving big piles of boulders, carving Fjords and generally ruggeding up the place. Yosemite in the States is a great example of this. 
[image: London]

The obvious answer that the North, Ireland and Scotland would have rolling hills and V-shaped valleys and England would look more like a warmer Sweden. Eastern England would be raising as the effects of the weight of the ice being lifted. The rest would actually be higher but more gentle.

There may be a land bridge between Northern Ireland and Scotland.

Here is a picture of a Fjord in Sweden I am thinking y'all could have these in Essex
[image: Essex]

Comment: There _was_ no English Channel during the ice age to be covered by ice. Sea levels were a lot lower, and Britain was part of the European mainland (although there was a very big river flowing where the Channel is now, combining the Thames, Rhine and many other rivers).

Comment: Very nice, I am afraid I have a Columbocentric failing. Do you mind if I add that to the answer? or I guess just remove it.

Comment: Yes, by all means edit the answer.

Comment: Where is that picture?

Comment: Downtown London in the ATL (Yosemite in ours)

Comment: @King-Ink  You assumed correct.  I've never seen a Swedish landscape, so could you please clarify?  And what does "higher but more gentle" mean?  And was there evidence of the potential for a landbridge between Northern Ireland and Scotland?

Comment: less lochs and craigs V-shaped rather than U-shaped Valleys I added a picture of a Fjord in Scandinavia.

Comment: @King-Ink  Is there evidence of the potential for a landbridge between Northern Ireland and Scotland?  Also, how did you submit the images there?

Comment: I was just speculating. look at underwater topographic maps and read the literature see what you come up with. There is a picture icon in edit.