# The Ice of Eurasia, in Full Detail

Tags: geography, ice

This post is related to both [If Britain Had Ice From a Different Direction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34318/if-britain-had-ice-from-a-different-direction) and [Turning the Baltic Sea into the Baltic Plain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34492/turning-the-baltic-sea-into-the-baltic-plain).

In OTL, the farthest south the ice reached in Europe was close to London.  All of Scandinavia was also buried in ice, giving birth to the Baltic Sea.  Although some areas were buried in ice, the majority of Russia was still ice-free.

In this alternate last ice age, the ice went as far down south as Paris and as far west as London.  Scandinavia remained buried in ice, but now the ice covered the Russian federal regions of Northwestern, Central, Volga, Southern, North Caucasian, the Urals and Siberia.

What kinds of differences should I expect to see in the terrain and topography of the affected areas?

Comment: I'd suggest requesting one region and extrapolating or asking additional follow on questions as needed.

Comment: Hohmannfan already beat you.

Comment: Started a meta discussion: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2981/world-under-ice-questions-too-broad

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing I can think of is that the [Isostatic depressing zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isostatic_depression) is going to be far larger, causing a large part of the Netherlands, Denmark, Northern Germany and western France to be lower than the sea level today. Furthermore, I would expect more fjords in Normandy and southern England.

The Baltic ocean is going to stretch a lot further into Poland and Russia, perhaps making Scandinavia an island.

Coastlines are going to be something like this:

[image: more ice]

The Arctic ocean floods the West Siberian planes, almost reaching Central Asia.

[image: Russia]